# problems with scallop and updating to scala 2.11

Tags: java, scala

I tried to update to Scala 2.11.0-M5, but I've run into problems. I use scallop so I needed to build that with Scala 2.11.0-M5 because I could not find a prebuilt jar. The compile of scallop goes fine but when I try to run "sbt publish-local" I get the errors below when it is trying to build the documentation. To me this looks like it is trying to build some sbt source file. I tried to find newer source for sbt (or an sbt jar built with scala 2.11.0-M5), but could not. Can anyone offer any suggestions?

thanks very much!

```
[info] Generating Scala API documentation for main sources to /Users/jetson/develop/scala/scala-2.11/scallop/target/scala-2.11/api...
[info] Compiling 12 Scala sources to /Users/jetson/develop/scala/scala-2.11/scallop/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.11.0-M5. Compiling...
/var/folders/m9/fn_sw0s970q02nf8cng94j640000gn/T/sbt_1dff5778/CompilerInterface.scala:246: error: recursive method rootLoader needs result type
            override def rootLoader = if(resident) newPackageLoaderCompat(rootLoader)(compiler.classPath) else super.rootLoader
                                                                                      ^
/var/folders/m9/fn_sw0s970q02nf8cng94j640000gn/T/sbt_1dff5778/CompilerInterface.scala:246: error: value rootLoader is not a member of scala.tools.nsc.backend.JavaPlatform
            override def rootLoader = if(resident) newPackageLoaderCompat(rootLoader)(compiler.classPath) else super.rootLoader
                                                                                                                                 ^
two errors found
[info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.11.0-M5. Compiling...
/var/folders/m9/fn_sw0s970q02nf8cng94j640000gn/T/sbt_4baba5ae/CompilerInterface.scala:246: error: recursive method rootLoader needs result type
            override def rootLoader = if(resident) newPackageLoaderCompat(rootLoader)(compiler.classPath) else super.rootLoader
                                                                                      ^
/var/folders/m9/fn_sw0s970q02nf8cng94j640000gn/T/sbt_4baba5ae/CompilerInterface.scala:246: error: value rootLoader is not a member of scala.tools.nsc.backend.JavaPlatform
            override def rootLoader = if(resident) newPackageLoaderCompat(rootLoader)(compiler.classPath) else super.rootLoader
                                                                                                                                 ^
two errors found
[error] (compile:doc) Error compiling sbt component 'compiler-interface'
[error] (compile:compile) Error compiling sbt component 'compiler-interface'
[error] Total time: 15 s, completed Oct 21, 2013 11:41:14 AM
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are actually building with sbt 0.13.x. If you've installed the latest version of sbt and still get this error then the sbt version is probably being overridden by the project/build.properties file.

Edit project/build.properties and so it includes sbt.version=0.13.2 or whatever the current sbt release is.

Comment: Thanks! This was my problem -- I didn't even realize sbt was loading up an old version.

Comment: I use maven, and upgrading the scala-maven-plugin to version 3.2.1 fixed it for me.